# What is the equivalent of a C/C++ global variable?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am new to C#. Come from the C/C++ environment. My application has a `List<Model>` which is required all over the place, by different classes. The problem is that a copy will not do because this statement:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = myModelList;
```

**requires** the original by address. I tried changing some arguments around and passing that particular variable as `ref` but as soon as it is assigned with an equal sign, I end up with a copy. Correct?

Comment: XY problem. 1 - There are no "global variables" (in the strict sense of the word) in C#. 2 - You shouldn't be messing with `ref` and stuff like that. 3 - `var a = someotherlist;` makes `a` equal to `someotherlist` BY Reference by default. What is the problem you're experiencing behind this?

Comment: No, you don't end up with a copy.  Equals sign copies the reference for reference types including `List<T>`.

Comment: I must hurry to add that there is threading in the middle!! <http://patriot.net/~ramon/misc/Threading.png>

Comment: @TravisBanger you probably need an `ObservableCollection` rather than a List.

Comment: The `MainWindow` reads a bunch of large XML files, placing the important fields in the right-hand DataGrids. Since processing can be slow, I added threading (being a total newbie on it). Most specifically, `ThreadPool, DispatcherInvoke`.

Comment: I am using `ObservableCollection`. Posted `List` for simplicity.

Comment: This is the correct link: http://patriot.net/~ramon/misc/Threading.png

Comment: I am convinced that one must develop the application sans-threads first, and make sure that everything works correctly. Only after that, one should venture into threading.

Comment: @TravisBanger not really. With .Net it's pretty much the same, just add `Task.Factory.StartNew()` or if you're using C# 5, `async / await`.

Comment: The original version used async/wait, but for some reason (need to run on XP, hate MSVS-2012) I first downgraded to BackgroundWorker. That was a **really bad** mistake. What a POS! Now I found the perfect solution: `ThreadPool, DispatcherInvoke`

Comment: @Travis, I definitely wouldn't start threading until I had a very clear idea of what I wanted to thread and I had tests for it.

Comment: @Tony: This is the 10th. variation of the application. It **definitely** requires the threads. I cannot have the user waiting for 60+ XML files to be processed before he finally sees the DataGrid rows. The app has had 3 different thread types plus no threads at all. In fact, now it works fine! I just took a copy of `MainWindow` (with `this`), saved the instance and refer to the `List<Model>` as follows: `instance.mylist`. My problem is that is looks kludgy. I will rethink the whole thing, based on the valuable info you folks have provided.

Comment: @Travis, no argument mate. I was just agreeing with you that leaping straight into threading is often a terrible idea.

Comment: @Tony: I wish there was a way to readily turn on/off the threading, to remove one source of uncertainty. The latest Windows thread approaches go in this direction, with all the threading code centralized in one function.

Answer (score 2):

You could make it a singleton.
However a concrete List needed all over the place would make me have a serious think about my design.

At the very least you should consider writing a class to control access to the list (add, remove, clear etc), and making that "global", otherwise you are going to be in deep in the brown stuff, until it  hits the fan.

Comment: Tony, what is the advantage of using a singleton in this case over a class with static members?

Comment: You can do more with one , and it demonstrates a particular intent, but I've no idea whether it's better in this case. I just posted it as an option as no one else had at the time, and there was not enough information provided by the OP to choose one over the other. It certainly doesn't solve all the problems choosing to make something global causes.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a public class for it with a public static List inside it. That one you then can access everywhere.

eg

```
public class FakeGlobal
{
    public static List<Model> MyModelList = new List<Model>();
}
```

or even make it a property with getter/setter.

Comment: It's not or even, it's do not fail to. Bad enough having global variable, one that any "fool" can change at any point and not know they've done something potentially horrible is just asking for it.

Comment: about setter/getter... I said that already at the bottom of the answer. But that's up to the developer to choose.

Comment: Well after decades in the game, I can assure I'd never choose to do what you posted. You'd need valuable hostages to make me even consider it.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson are you referring to the not having a setter part? Or the entire concept of the public class used for general/global variables?

Comment: Well if I could avoid the global I would, if I couldn't I'd make sure I could at least log the fact someone just swapped the list I need everywhere for a completely different one that will now be available everywhere. With a setter, it would have made me grimace, but I wouldn't have felt a need to comment.

Comment: I disagree. There's no point adding the overhead of a getter/setter just for the sake of it. By all means use 'em if you need to (i.e. different protection levels, change notification etc) but don't just use them for the sake of DP snobbery. Many languages (e.g. Java) don't support them and there's a good chance your code may one day need to be ported to a lower-end architecture where such practices are severely frowned upon for performance reasons. Every time you add a language-specific feature to your code you make it that less portable, always keep that in mind.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Hehe, this is exactly the reason why I stated , 'it's up to the developer to choose'. Everyone has his/her own vision on stuff. Though I agree with Tony...

Comment: A reasonable (IMO) counter-argument to my comment above is that the "correct" solution would probably be to use a dependency injection framework, and for that to work you need to use getters and setters :) You're absolutely right though, it should depend entirely on the specific circumstances.

Comment: @MarkFeldman. Snobbery? I was thinking some unit tests that might actually be worth the effort of writing...

Answer (score 1):

Create a Public Class and have the content you wish to pass declared static within the class.  Then just access it as NameOfClass.NameOfMethod()

```
public class NameOfClass
{
    public static RETURNTYPE NameOfMethod()
    {
        // Your Code
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this thread safe? Where is the `List<Model>`? Between the 2 publics?